# Import schema into BigQuery via R

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I have a folder containing:

```
-- schema.yml
-- table1.csv
-- table2.csv
-- table4.csv
```

This folder is stored locally.

I looked around for a while and I want to ask:

Is there a way to batch upload this schema into BigQuery directly from R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `R` with `bigquery`. [Bigquery documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/workbench/user-managed/use-r-bigquery) recommends to use [tibble](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/index.html) in conjuntion with [bigrquery](https://bigrquery.r-dbi.org).

**bigrquery**

This package implements the [bigquery rest API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest), where you can make use of [low_level_api](https://bigrquery.r-dbi.org/reference/) in the package to perform bigquery operations.

For your specific case, you can [read](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) your `schema.yml` file and use it to create the table fields data and create the [bq_fields](https://bigrquery.r-dbi.org/reference/bq_field.html) needed to create your table trough [bq_table](https://bigrquery.r-dbi.org/reference/api-table.html) .In the last bit, you can read the files and create either a single file or an iteration to populate your table. This will depend in your criteria and the amount of data you are handling.

Here is a small sample to get starting using tibble with bigrquery in a notebook. ( I use a R python notebook from GCP )

```
library(tibble)
library(bigrquery)

# authenticate
# use if notebook is outside gcp
#bigrquery::bq_auth(path = '/Users/me/restofthepath/bigquery-credentials.json')

# set my project ID and dataset name
project_id <- '<my-project-id>'
dataset_name <- '<my-dataset-name>'

# set fields
sample_fields<-list(
  bq_field(name = "name", type = "string"),
  bq_field("age", "integer")
)

# set values
sample_df<-tribble(
   ~name,  ~age,
   "erika",  21,
   "isabel", 18, 
)

# create table and upload your values
sample_table = bq_table(project = project_id, dataset = dataset_name, table = '<my-table-name>')
bq_table_create(x = sample_table, fields = as_bq_fields(sample_fields))
bq_table_upload(x = sample_table, values = sample_df, create_disposition='CREATE_IF_NEEDED', write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND')
```

**Note**: you may need to implement the env and install the libraries. For it you can do this:

```
# install libraries
install.packages("bigrquery")
install.packages("tibble")

# set env
print(Sys.setenv(BIGQUERY_TEST_PROJECT = "<my-project-id>"))  
Sys.getenv("BIGQUERY_TEST_PROJECT")
```